# Getting error on admin customer edit after Magento updated to 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

I am getting error when I try to edit customer from Admin side.

Error:

Magento\AdminAdobeIms\Plugin\RemovePasswordAndUserConfirmationFormFieldsPlugin::afterGetForm(): Argument #2 ($result) must be of type Magento\Framework\Data\Form, null given, called in /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146
Exception in /html/vendor/magento/module-admin-adobe-ims/Plugin/RemovePasswordAndUserConfirmationFormFieldsPlugin.php:39

[image]
Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be related to other 3rd party modules,

You can check in whole log, the Extension name will be there and then you can debug the module or upgrade it if required.

Please check here. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36145

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Yes, the issue is from my custom module.

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Yashir this is the same error I have also faced but not in customer edit but in the configuration we have created a custom form and tab due to this error.To resolve this I had to override the get form method in our custom form file here is the sample.
[image]

**Solution which worked for me :**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Block\Adminhtml\Configuration\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class FiscalCalendar extends Generic implements TabInterface
{

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param Data $helper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    public function getForm()
    {
        if ($this->_form == null) {
            return $this->_formFactory->create();
        } else {
            return $this->_form;
        }
    }
```